# What the heck is going on in Javascript scopes and hoisting?

Tags: javascript, scope, hoisting

**Based on my current knowledge**, I faced something really unexpected in Javascript.
Consider this simple code:

```
foo();
if(true){
  function foo(){
    console.log(i);
  }
}
foo();
```

I know that variable and function declarations will be hoisted by the Js engine at the **creation phase**. In this example the function *foo* will be hoisted and when **creation phase** is done. The engine will start to run the code line by line, at the first line of the code a function called *foo* should be invoked. We have that function, because it was hoisted before right? the problem is here a *TypeError* will be thrown which says that *foo* is not a function.
And when I remove the *if block* everything works well. I think it's somehow related to the block scopes but don't know how exactly and why it behaves like this.

What's going on here?

> I know that function declarations should not be placed in blocks.

Comment: "*I know that function declarations should not be placed in blocks.*" - then don't do it :-) Also make sure to use strict mode.

Comment: "*What's going on here?*" - the block scope has its own creation phase.

Comment: @Bergi   `then don't do it`,  I assume this is only if inside a loop these days,  or if you really do have to target ES5.

Comment: @Keith Yeah, I was trying to be quippy. Actually I'm all for declaring functions in block scopes where it makes sense. The advice should be to "*…then don't try to call it outside of that block*", really.